# Automatically zoom page out to max or certain % when loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, web, zooming

I was wondering if there is any javascript code that zooms a webpage out to max (till no horizontal scrolling is possible) so that it looks good on mobile.

I've used:

```
document.body.style.zoom="x%"
```

But it will only allow me to zoom in. Zooming out, or putting a percentage higher than 100%, does not have any effect.

Comment: You should be looking at your CSS files. All values in CSS should be percentages or ems so that all the page will fit to the viewport. You might also want to use media queries as this is what they were designed to handle.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use the browser object model to get height and width then use JavaScript to set the view container to the dimensions returned, another option is to set the body container to height: 100% width: 100% but depending how the page is designed it has to be tested. Using zoom which is not guaranteed to be implemented sounds like a bad option. A better option would be conditional JavaScript to render the view container according to BOM